# Memory error when using overloaded addition operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading, python-class

I overloaded addition operator in the class `P1` to make the instances can be added together directly. However, memory error happens when doing `p1 + p2`. `p1.data + p2.data` can give the right result.

```
class P1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.zeros((512,512),dtype='float64')
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.data + other
    
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + self.data

p1 = P1()
p2 = P1()
p1 + p2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\professional\Anaconda_install\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-224-a0c3d63f397c>", line 1, in <module>
    p1 + p2
  File "<ipython-input-221-ba43c19b29b0>", line 12, in __add__
    return self.data + other
  File "<ipython-input-221-ba43c19b29b0>", line 15, in __radd__
    return other + self.data
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.00 MiB for an array with shape (512, 512) and data type float64
```

Could anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 1):

The overload occurs because you've said `other` instead of `other.data` in `__add__` and `__radd__` which creates a [Feedback Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback).

To elaborate, you started by calling `p1.__add__(p2)`, which causes the interpreter to look for `p2.__radd__(p1)`, which repeats the process because `p2.__radd__(p1)` looks for `p1.__add__(p2)`.

That is, it never manages to return because its looking things up, saving values to finish the computation after more data is found, and depleting the available memory in this endless process.

### solution:

```py
import numpy as np

class P1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.zeros((512,512),dtype='float64')
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]

    def __add__(self, other):
        # return self.data + other.data
        return np.array([*self.data, *other.data])
    def __radd__(self, other):
        # return other.data + self.data
        return np.array([*other.data, *self.data])
```

Though technically you could just swap one of `__add__` or `__radd__` and the operator overload will still work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Why it works when self.data is a value and fails when self.data is an array? Could you please explain more about what happens when the interpreter call `p2.__radd__(p1)` and `p1.__add__(p2)`?

Comment: Because python lists don't have an ```__radd__``` attribute. I personally can't go into that much detail about interpreters but ```__add__``` and ```__radd__``` are simply "magic" or "dunder" (double-underscore) methods which give the classes that have them the "syntactic sugar" of ```a + b``` and ```b + a```, respectively. Whenever you use the operator notation on an object the interpreter looks for its magic method so that it knows what to do. If it can't find one it raises an error. Technically you could put any old thing in there

Comment: Edited the post, that should work better. I didn't realize lists didn't have ```__radd__```.